# Windows Server 2019 Essentials RAM limitation

Tags: windows, memory, windows-server-2019

I have one machine with WS2019 Essentials and see that this version use only max 64 GB RAM. Now I have insert free 32 GB RAM for it and this RAM is "hardware reserved" - is any possibility to use this RAM normally? Any hack to grow up limit (without buying standard license). This 32 GB RAM I want to use with one VM in Hyper-V maybe I can configure hyper-v to use this hardware reserved memory?

Answer (score 1):

Like previous releases, Windows Server 2019 Essential is limited to 64 GB RAM, no way around it.

You'll need to upgrade to Standard or higher to overcome that limit. Beware of the quite different (CAL) licensing.

Comment: ok ;/ maybe I can do swap from this 32Gb ram or something diffrent that OS or HyperV can use ?

Comment: Windows simply ignores the memory exceeding 64 GB completely. You can't use it for swapping, with Hyper-V, or anything else. You do need another OS (edition).

Comment: ok, I have bought new key for standard editon. Now my questions is:  it is safe to upgrade OS which is domain controller from essential to standard version which this tutorial https://jarviecomputing.com.au/2020/12/23/upgrade-server-2019-essentials-to-server-standard-2019-ms-licensing/
??

Comment: It should work, with the usual caveats (have a current, disaster-recoverable image backup, prepare properly, allocate sufficient time, ...). I usually do a clean reinstall and then migrate data & services. If you do migrate, don't forget the AD roles if that's the AD master.

Comment: damn, on Standard edition I need also rds lic, I have 10 users in ad and essentials have up to 25 user/machines ;(

Comment: Yeah - MS is using the Essentials (and Small Business earlier) as bait for low-budget users. I've added a note to the answer for future readers.

Comment: I will try to make hyper-v server on local machine then migrate OS ws2019 essential to vhdx then run it on hyper-v and second vm for this machine which should use this 32gb ram which is not avalible on ws2019 esentials